# INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger fired while updating table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have an `Instead of Insert` trigger which looks like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgBeforeInsertVehicleFeed] ON [dbo].[VehicleFeed]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

insert into VehicleFeed(
    FeedOrDealerId                  
    , Name                      
    , Vin                       
    , Stock                 
    , VehicleType           
    , StatusId              
    , IsManualEntry 
    , IsActive              
)
    select 
        I.FeedOrDealerId                
        , I.Name                    
        , I.Vin                 
        , I.Stock               
        , I.VehicleType 
        , I.StatusId            
        , I.IsManualEntry
        , I.IsActive
    from inserted I

    select distinct FeedOrDealerId from inserted

    Update VehicleFeed
    Set 
        IsActive= 0
        , StatusId = 11                     
    Where
        Stock Not In (select stock from inserted)
        And FeedOrDealerId = (select Distinct FeedOrDealerId from inserted)
        And IsManualEntry = (select Distinct IsManualEntry from inserted)
        And IsManualEntry = 0
END
```

There are two statements in it. The first one is `insert` and other one is `update`.

So this trigger is working properly on `insert`. But the issue is this trigger is also fired while updating the any record. While I update any record, its status become 11 as mentioned in trigger and this status is used only in this trigger.

Comment: can you recheck,if there any other trigger exists in table VehicleFeed .or check all triggers which update table VehicleFeed

Comment: What's with the rogue `select` statement in the middle? Triggers that return result sets tend to produce hideous experiences.

Comment: "this trigger is also fired while updating". Almost certainly, this conclusion is wrong. Unfortunately, you've not really given us enough information to diagnose *how* you came to this conclusion, but it's wrong.